# mod_wsgi Error: ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.so, 2): Symbol not found: _iconv

Tags: python, apache, opencv, mod-wsgi

I am configuring a Python application which uses OpenCV with Apache (XAMPP) on MacOSx (El Capitan) system. And, I am using [mod_wsgi](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/). mod_wsgi has been successfully (and correctly) built with Python3.6 and XAMPP's apache version as per the installation guide.

I have used before a Python application (without OpenCV) with Apache using mod_wsgi and it has worked correctly already.

However, I have now another application which uses OpenCV and I am getting the following error (error log from Apache) which I do not have any idea about, morever I did not find something similar in the internet:

```
[Tue Jul 18 12:12:53.547655 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 19030] [remote ::1:51718]
import cv2
[Tue Jul 18 12:12:53.547686 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 19030] [remote ::1:51718] 
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.so, 2): Symbol not found: _iconv
[Tue Jul 18 12:12:53.547698 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 19030] [remote ::1:51718]
Referenced from: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/Versions/A/LanguageModeling
[Tue Jul 18 12:12:53.547706 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 19030] [remote ::1:51718]   Expected in: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
[Tue Jul 18 12:12:53.547713 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 19030] [remote ::1:51718]  in /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/Versions/A/LanguageModeling
```

Output of **/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.so**:

```
@rpath/libopencv_shape.3.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.2.0, current version 3.2.0)
@rpath/libopencv_superres.3.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.2.0, current version 3.2.0)
@rpath/libopencv_stitching.3.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.2.0, current version 3.2.0)
@rpath/libopencv_videostab.3.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.2.0, current version 3.2.0)
@rpath/libopencv_objdetect.3.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.2.0, current version 3.2.0)
@rpath/libopencv_photo.3.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.2.0, current version 3.2.0)
@rpath/libopencv_video.3.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.2.0, current version 3.2.0)
@rpath/libopencv_calib3d.3.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.2.0, current version 3.2.0)
@rpath/libopencv_features2d.3.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.2.0, current version 3.2.0)
@rpath/libopencv_flann.3.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.2.0, current version 3.2.0)
@rpath/libopencv_ml.3.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.2.0, current version 3.2.0)
@rpath/libopencv_highgui.3.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.2.0, current version 3.2.0)
@rpath/libopencv_videoio.3.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.2.0, current version 3.2.0)
@rpath/libopencv_imgcodecs.3.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.2.0, current version 3.2.0)
@rpath/libopencv_imgproc.3.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.2.0, current version 3.2.0)
@rpath/libopencv_core.3.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.2.0, current version 3.2.0)
/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 307.4.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1238.0.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible reason for the problem and solution: Problem arises here from XAMPP. XAMPP uses dynamic libraries (for example: libiconv.dylib, libtiff.dylib etc.) which are loaded/linked when Apache server is started. These libraries can be found in `Applications/XAMPP/xampfiles/lib`. Of course, these libraries have certain versions.

Some of these libraries also exist in the MacOS system libraries, which can be found in `/usr/lib`. These libraries might have different versions than the XAMPP ones. This causes a conflict when OpenCV is used because when OpenCV is built (either from source code or by using Brew command), it links some of the OpenCV native dynamic libraries with the system libraries.

Now, when XAMPP's apache server is used, it somehow forces OpenCV to not use system libraries, rather it uses its own dynamic libraries. And, because of different versions, it causes a conflict which leads to errors likes: `Symbol not found: _iconv` or `Incompatible Library versions`. It uses XAMPP library (libiconv.dylib) rather than the same corresponding MacOS's library. In the XAMPP's libiconv.dylib, this symbol does not exists, however, it does exists in MacOS's libiconv.dylib. This can be checked by using the following command:

```
nm /usr/lib/libiconv.dylib | grep iconv
nm Applcations/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/libiconv.dylib | grep iconv
```

Even, by manually adding `LoadFile /usr/lib/libiconv.dylib` in the Apache's configuration file does not work out as suggested by **Grapham Dumpleton**.

So, instead of using the XAMPP's apache, I have used the MacOS's default Apache server. It has worked out correctly. I think it is because MacOS's Apache uses the system libraries which also OpenCV uses, therefore, there does not exist conflict anymore.

Note: in order to use the MacOS's apache server, you need to configure everything again (PHP, MySQL Server and phpMyAdmin). Follow [this link](http://appledigg.com/t/tutorial-to-install-webserver-and-get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-mac-os-x-10-11-el-capitan/579) for the configuration.

Also, you need to build [mod_wsgi](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/installation.html) again because of very possible different versions of Apache in XAMPP and in default MacOS.

Comment: Just be aware that even when use Apple version of Apache, one shared library conflict can occur. This is if you are using Python 3.6+ from the PSF as it bundles its own OpenSSL library. If you use mod_ssl in Apache, it drags in the system SSL libraries which override Python ones, and so conflicts arise and things don't work. If using Python 3.6 it is therefore impossible to use mod_ssl in Apache.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like when the C extension for cv2 was compiled, it assumed that the `libiconv` library was already linked into the Python executable, rather than still linking it itself. When Python is embedded in Apache, as Apache is not linking in the `libiconv` library, the function is missing.

As a workaround, add the following line to the Apache configuration outside of any `VirtualHost` definitions.

```
LoadFile /usr/lib/libiconv.dylib
```

Comment: I just added the provided "LoadFile" statement in my virtual host. However, it is still showing the same error. Interestingly, before it was showing a similar kind of error with "libtiff.5.dylib" file (Library not loaded and Incompatible library version) and then, I compiled OpenCV without libtiff. And, now it shows the present error (symbol not error).

Comment: I just checked the files present in "/usr/lib" directory and found the following related files: libiconv.dylib, libiconv.2.dylib and libiconv.2.4.0.dylib. And, permissions are lrwxr-xr-x , -r-xr-xr-x and lrwxr-xr-x . Permissions are also fine.

Comment: What do you get when you run ``otool -L /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.so``? Do you have a ``libiconv`` library installed using Brew and was that perhaps used when cv2 package was built, meaning you should load it instead?

Comment: I have updated the output of "otool -L" in my question. Please have a look there. Hmm, regarding "libiconv" I did not have any idea before I built OpenCV (cv2 package). I have never used it before. I just omitted, i.e., --without-libtiff since it was causing the library not loaded error.
Do you think I should re-built again OpenCV? But, before install libiconv using brew command?

Comment: Avoid installing ``libiconv`` from Brew. That would likely just confuse things. What do you get if you run ``nm /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.so | grep iconv``.

Comment: There is no output from the command. Its really strange. From my feeling, there is somewhere wrong linking or loading of the libraries either from Apache or WSGI or OpenCV side because now I built again OpenCV (using "brew install opencv --with-python3 --without-python "(this means not for Python2.7)). I get back the old "Library not loaded error" (libtiff.dylib). However, when I use OpenCV in the terminal or in Spyder IDE, it is successfully loaded. I think if we are able to correct loading "libtiff.dylib", then it will show some other error (for example "iconv" or any other library loading).

Comment: Try adding a ``LoadFile`` line to pre-load ``libtiff.dylib``. BTW, are you using PHP in the same Apache instance? Problems can sometimes arise when PHP is being used and it is pulling in a different version of a library. That library will end up taking precedence and could cause problems.

Comment: Yes, I have already tried LoadFile to load libtiff.dylib in a virtualhost. But, still it did not work out. Yes, that might be a problem, however, I tried to set up the same configuration in two different computers (one is using PHP and other has no PHP code). Unfortunately, same error is showing up in both computers. Do you think if MacOS is influencing something here?

Comment: Hi Graham, I have found the solution finally! I have tried the same project in another computer which has Ubuntu installation. My project has worked without any problem. So, the problem comes from XAMPP's Apache. I am writing the solution in the answer part. Thanks a lot for your kind help.

Comment: Third party distributions, or less common ones, on both MacOS X and Windows can often be a problem. They either require use of their own bundled libraries and so are incompatible with the Python distribution, or don't even supply header files to allow you to build additional Apache modules properly.

Comment: Exactly the same happens with the XAMPP. What I have found that it forces to use its own libraries rather than using the system libraries which OpenCV uses. This causes the conflict like incompatible library versions or it cannot find certain symbol in XAMPP's library which do exist in the system library. So, solution for me was to not use XAMPP anymore, rather use the default MacOS's apache. I have answered this question already and please feel free to edit and comment it, if something is required. Thanks again!